# How to only show the RightSide Slide Menu View Controller in MFSideMenu?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

i am Newbie in iOS Development i want to make an Slide Out menu in iOS For that i Use [MFSideOutMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) but i want to Show only Left Side Slide Out menu where in this MFSideOutMenu that Contain both Side Menu left and Right Method like as

```
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];
```

when i write in this method only leftMenuViewController then it Display Error please Give me Solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass `nil` to rightMenuViewController and that should do it. You should pass `nil` to the side which you do not wish to have.

```
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                            containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                            leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                            rightMenuViewController:nil];
```